# How to remove duplicate instances of class

Tags: javascript

In javascript, I am trying to apply an 'active' class upon clicking a button. However, I would then like to remove the class from the button which previously had it. I'm not sure how to best go about this. I was considering something involving a second loop after the click, but that seems somewhat convoluted, and like there's probably a better way. Here's the code I have to add the class, but again, not sure how to best go about removing it from the button to which it was previously applied.

```
const giftcards = document.querySelectorAll('.giftcard');

for(let giftcard of giftcards){
  giftcard.onclick = () => {
    giftcard.classList.add('active');
  }
}
```

Comment: You want to remove all existing classes or one particular class for which you know it’s name?

Comment: One particular class. Another 'giftcard' would have the class 'active' applied to it, but upon clicking on another one, I would like that class removed from the element to which it was previously applied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is always at most one `.giftcard` with an `active` class you could query for that giftcard before setting `active` to the currently clicked one using `document.querySelector('.giftcard.active')` and utilize [Optional chaining (?.)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) to remove the `active` class only if an element was found.

```js
const giftcards = document.querySelectorAll('.giftcard');

for (let giftcard of giftcards) {
  giftcard.onclick = () => {
    document.querySelector('.giftcard.active')?.classList.remove('active');
    giftcard.classList.add('active');
  }
}
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="giftcard">card 1</div>
<div class="giftcard">card 2</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div>
  <button class="giftcard">Button 1</button>
  <button class="giftcard">Button 1</button>
  <button class="giftcard">Button 1</button>
</div>
<script>
  const giftcards = document.querySelectorAll(".giftcard");
  giftcards.forEach((giftcard) => {
    giftcard.addEventListener("click", () => {
      giftcardClick(giftcard);
    });
  });
  function giftcardClick(giftcard) {
    giftcards.forEach((giftcard) => {
      giftcard.classList.remove("active");
    });
    giftcard.classList.add("active");
  }
</script>
```